# Parsing c struct to java interface

Tags: java, c, parsing, struct, converters

Are there any tools that I can use to parse c struct to java interface automatically?
an example would be:

```
typedef struct C {
    int x;
    byte y;
}C;

//Java
interface C {
    public int x();
    public byte y();
    public void x(int val);
    public void y(byte val);
}
```

Comment: There is no `byte` (or `btye`) type in C right?

Comment: It's not directly about code transformation because it has a slightly different syntax but might be one useful tool in your pipeline: https://github.com/marc-christian-schulze/structs4java

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try regular expression replaces.
In Java for example:

```
String javaCode = cCode.replaceAll("(\\w+) +(\\w+);", "public void $1 $2();\n    public $1 x($1 $2);");
```

Demo here: http://regexr.com?388h8

Now, just a minimal effort is needed to change the syntax of the struct definition itself.

Comment: this is only an example, with a big struct, regular expression is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Javolution](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html) is a library that provides this kind of functionality in an easy way, example taken from the documentation:

```
public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE };
public static class Date extends Struct {
  public final Unsigned16 year = new Unsigned16();
  public final Unsigned8 month = new Unsigned8();
  public final Unsigned8 day   = new Unsigned8();
}
public static class Student extends Struct {
  public final Enum32<Gender>       gender = new Enum32<Gender>(Gender.values());
  public final UTF8String           name   = new UTF8String(64);
  public final Date                 birth  = inner(new Date());
  public final Float32[]            grades = array(new Float32[10]);
  public final Reference32<Student> next   =  new Reference32<Student>();
}
```

Comment: Javolution and other library(JNA) only provide the way of converting, they are not tools for automatically convert from c to Java

Comment: If you want to avoid translating such a specific thing because you are lazy / have many of them the only solution I see is to write a simple parser in lex/yacc or antlr. If a tool doesn't exist, just roll your own. A lexer/parser to translate them would be really easy.